# Server variable in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Is there any way to access server side asp.net variable in javascript? I want to do something like

```
function setBookmark(val)
{
    document.getElementById('<%# hBookmark.ClientID %>').value=val;
}
```

Is it possible in anyway?

***Note***: hBookmark is a server side html hiddent control, I want to use client ID as IDs are changed as the server controls are rendered.

Comment: Note: hBookmark is a server side html hiddent control, I want to use client ID as IDs are changed as the server controls are rendered.

Comment: This should work fine, are you running into a problem? I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Use <%=, not <%#
document.getElementById('<%= hBookmark.ClientID %>').value = val;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use scriptlets like this...

```
document.getElementById('<%= hBookmark.ClientID %>').value = val;
```

But note that the Javascript can not reside in an external file; it must be in the markup for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the variable as value for a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= hBookmark.ClientID %>" id="hBookmarkClientID" />
```

And then use it from JavaScript

```
function setBookmark(val)
{
    var hBookmarkClientID=document.getElementById('hBookmarkClientID').value;

    document.getElementById(hBookmarkClientID).value=val;
}
```